# Mongodb remove orphaned documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

There are several posts related to this, but none seem to fit my need. 
I have a large collection blocks (approx 8m objects) and it references projects (approx 700k objects). A large number of blocks are orphaned and I want to remove them.

The structure is basically:
**Projects Collection Schema**

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(...),
  ....
  blocks: [
    ObjectId(...),
    ....
    ObjectId(...)
  ]
  ...

}
```

**Blocks Collection Schema**

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(...),
  ....
  projectId: ObjectId(...),

}
```

I've looked at using something similar to this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/HzkXDmgjS20) however the numbers are too large. I'm using Mongo 3.4 server on Atlas.

Comment: "A large number of blocks are orphaned and I want to remove them." -> let me get this straight, the blocks array of documents inside the projects collection sometimes contains references to blocks that no longer exist?

Comment: maybe you need like to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19340038/db-clonecollection-ignore-duplicate-keys